# ¿Qué fallo de búfer hay en mi código?

Tags: java

Esta vez tengo una duda en cuanto a mi código.

Los objetivos de mi código son:

- Comprobar si es un numero.
- Comprobar si el numero es superior a 10.

El problema es que cuando introduzco un numero fura del rango (el programa me va decir carácter invalido) y después introduzco una letra el programa falla, lo cual es extraño por que si no haces esta secuencia de caracteres inválidos el código no falla.

Es decir, si primero introduces una letra y después un numero menor a 10 nada falla.

Éste es mi código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce un numero mayor a 10");
    int numero = 0;
    int invertido = 0;
    int operador;
    int resto;
    int contador = 0;
    
    while(!sc.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("Numero invalido");
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    do{
        numero=sc.nextInt();
        if(numero < 10){
            System.out.println("una cifra invalida");
        }else{
            System.out.println("cifra valida");
            contador++;
        }
    }while(contador < 1);
    
    operador = numero;
    
    while(operador >0){
        resto = operador % 10;
        invertido = invertido * 10 + resto;
        operador /=10; 
    }
    if(numero == invertido){
        System.out.println("Tu numero se puede leer igual al revez: " + numero + " == " + invertido);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Tu numero no se puede leer al revez: " + numero + " != "  + invertido);
    }        
    
}
```

Comment: Error detectado, redactando respuesta.

Comment: ¿Puedes comprobar si la respuesta que te he redactado soluciona tu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si como dices se trata de:

- Comprobar si es un numero.
- Comprobar si el numero es superior a 10.

Entonces, de entrada puedes abrir un bloque `do ... while` que se ejecute hasta que el número sea superior a `10`. Y al interno, mediante otro bloque `while` buscas el entero `hasNextInt()`. Es importante invocar a `next()` dentro de ese segundo `while`. Y es que la verificación de `contador` no tiene sentido, para el propósito que expones en la pregunta.

El código podría quedar así:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numero;
    int invertido = 0;
    int operador;
    int resto;
    int contador = 0; //Esta variable no se usa
    String msg="Introduce un número mayor a 10";
    System.out.println(msg);
    do {
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.printf("No es un entero. %s%n",msg);
            sc.next();
        }
        numero = sc.nextInt();
        if ( numero < 10 ) {
            System.out.printf("El número no cumple el criterio. %s%n",msg);
        }else{
            operador = numero;
            while(operador > 0){
                resto = operador % 10;
                invertido = invertido * 10 + resto;
                operador /=10;
            }
            System.out.printf(numero == invertido ? 
                                "%1$d=%2$d Puede leerse invertido" : 
                                "%1$d!=%2$d No Puede leerse invertido",
                                numero,invertido);
        }
    } while (numero < 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un error colocando la limpieza del espacio de entrada. Lo ejecutas una única vez antes de empezar el bucle, pero deberías hacerlo en cada iteración:

```
do {
    while (sc.hasNextInt() == false) {
        System.out.println("Número inválido");
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    numero = sc.nextInt();
    if (numero < 10) {
        System.out.println("una cifra invalida");
    } else {
        System.out.println("cifra valida");
        contador++;
    }
} while(contador < 1);
```

De esta manera, por cada iteración del bucle `do .. while()` limpiarás el espacio de entrada cuando la cifra sea incorrecta, permitiendo leer la siguiente correctamente.

Comment: Gracias esto me sirve